# How to fix overscanning with nVidia 9800 GT? On Live Cd it wasn't happening?

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, graphics, live-cd

As the title says, i'm looking for a way to resolve it. in nvidia-settings I've found the overscanning resizer, but the screen looks awful!
It was looking perfect on the live cd! What should I do?

P.S. I've got two driver versions: "current" and "post-release". Which is better? What are the differences?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out, but it is for 8400 GS. [Overscan Fix for Nvidia Graphics Cards](http://ubuntuforum.webs.com/screenresolution.htm)